# Can I mount a large TV on flat studs with lag screws?

Tags: television, mount

Trying to mount my 75" tv and ran into a double wall. Starting from the room is 5/8" drywall, 2x4s 24"o/c laid on the flat side, vapour barrier, 6" gap and then the exterior wall. Will 4 lag bolts/screws hold up the weight of the mount and tv by only drilling into 1.5" of wood? Weight of TV and mount is approximately 130 lbs.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's fine, assuming you pilot properly. You'd ordinarily only be going that deep into lumber anyway.

Pre-drill slightly smaller than the screw shaft diameter (not the threads).

Comment: ok thanks. My nervousness is because the instructions for the mount say the lags need to be drilled to a depth of 3.75"

Comment: You're welcome. Please take the [tour] to learn how to use this site.

Comment: Top tip to predrill a little small. Make sure everything is accurate, tight and cannot sag.